# Fetch array object value in twig

Tags: php, twig

Hi I have an array with stdClass object and the array is in variable ($variable)

```
stdClass Object
(
    [attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [modTime] => 2014-07-01-10:35
            [status] => current
        )

    [agentID] => 26721
    [clientID] => siggroup
    [uniqueID] => 6660337
    [authority] => stdClass Object
        (
            [attributes] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => exclusive
                )

        )

    [underOffer] => stdClass Object
        (
            [attributes] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => no
                )

        )
)
```

if it is php i can call underOffer by following code:

```
echo $variable->underOffer->attributes->value;
```

please help me out, how can I call this using twig?
thanks in advance

Comment: `{{ variable.underOffer.attributes.value }}`

Comment: thanks one more issue, variable is a string with json objects, how can i use json_decode($variable) in twig

Comment: You should decode it in the controller, it's not the job of the view.

Comment: Twig is a template rendering engine not a scripting language; so you cannot decode your json in twig; Maybe you don't need to pass encoded json string to your twig, you need to pass the stdClass object instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% set property_uo = wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_object', TRUE) %}
{% set check_for_uo = wp.json_decode(property_uo) %}
{% if check_for_uo.underOffer.attributes.value == 'yes' %}
do something                            
{% else %}
```

This is what I did, I think it was pre defined in the wordpress theme (realia), thanks for helping everybody

Comment: You should do most of that outside the template. The template shouldn't be fetching any data from the database.